# Location services issue in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode

I m using location delegate methods to get the current location of the user.Everything is working fine when i debug it using xcode 7.3 but when I debug it using latest Xcode 8 and turn off location service from settings,in that case the pop up of location service disable and pop up to ask permission to get the location continuously appears on the screen and it freezes the app screen until the phone is restarted.

This is the code in AppDelegate class

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

    NSLog(@"locationManager didUpdateLocations: %@",locations);
    for(int i=0;i<locations.count;i++){
        CLLocation * newLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:i];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D theLocation = newLocation.coordinate;
        CLLocationAccuracy theAccuracy = newLocation.horizontalAccuracy;
        self.myLocation = theLocation;
        self.myLocationAccuracy = theAccuracy;
    }
    if (self.shareModel.afterResume==TRUE) {
       appStatus=@"Killed";
    self.locationTracker = [[LocationTracker alloc]init];

    self.locationTracker.str_latitude=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",self.myLocation.latitude];
    self.locationTracker.str_longitude=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",self.myLocation.longitude];
    self.locationTracker.pushStatus=FALSE;
    [self.locationTracker GetDevice_LocationSettings];
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

These two pop up comes one after another and doesn't allow to do any other action.

Comment: I am not sure. But just to know, What have you used in plist file for the location. Have you used "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription", or "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription". If it is always, can try the other one. may be asking always permission cause that issue. Let me know

Comment: I your app is frozen because "pop up to ask permission to get the location continuously" is appearing, I'd like to see the code where you try to enable/ask permission of the user.  Does it get called repeatedly or only just once?

Comment: @Janmenjaya in plist i m using :Privacy - Location Always Usage Description

Comment: @MichaelDautermann :   if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
            [self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        }i m using this in didfinishlaunching in appdelegate and two more places in other classes

Comment: Did you check by setting that to  "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription". Because I doubt, Apple may have considered this as restriction scenario : You asked the app to use location service to use always and again not allowing the location from settings. If so definitely Apple has to resolve this so as not to make the device to function like yours (If they restricted for the reason i mentioned then they must make the OS to show the alert once not like multiple times). But Its my perception, Can you check and let me know, If that way works and then can confirm about the bug?

Comment: @Janmenjaya i have change to NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription but that doesnt work even.Then in appdelegate applicationDidBecomeActive I commented [self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges]; then it is showing that pop up only 2 times.